# integrate nagios core with hp nmmi

Tags: nagios, snmp

I have one nagios core server . One of my partner companies request me to get snmp trap from nagios core to their HP NNMi system for some servers . I would like to ask you about integration between Nagios Core & HP NNMi. I searched in internet about that integration. But I don't get any satisfied ways. As my opinion, I will need one third party plugin to sent snmp trap to HP NNMi but I'm not sure about which plugins is the best for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that Nagios supports natively, so to speak.

You could write a notification script that uses `snmptrap` to send traps, as detailed in [this howto that is the top Google result for "nagios send snmp trap"](http://askaralikhan.blogspot.com/2010/02/sending-snmp-traps-from-nagios.html).